# Can't find ReportViewer event for rendering complete

Tags: asp.net, events, reportviewer

I'm trying to fire an event (to remove a custom progress/status indicator) when the ReportViewer control is finished rendering.  I've explored the events for the ReportViewer control and I can't seem to find one that actually fires when the report is complete.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET 4.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to continuously poll the [isLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756413.aspx) property of the [client side ReportViewer api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx).  If the isLoading property returns true continue showing the progress indicator, if it returns false hide it and stop polling.

I haven't tried it myself but according to the documentation is look like it should work.

Comment: Josh,
You were right on target.  I must have overlooked the client-side ReportViewer API somewhere.  
Below is code I used to tell my Silverlight app to do something when the report was finished loading:
`                var rptViewer = $find("<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>");
                 var statusHider = setInterval(function () {
                     if (!rptViewer.get_isLoading()) {
                         slCtl.Content.SilverlightApp.HideStatus();
                         clearInterval(statusHider);
                     }
                 }, 500);`

Comment: Should probably update the answer with that code instead of mashing it into a comment.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but I wasn't satisfied with the polling approach. You can register a property change listener for changes to isLoading instead (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx)).

In summary, add a bit of javascript to the script manager e.g. in your form element:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Reports/ReportViewer.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server"/>
```

Then hook it up and add any client-side logic you need in ReportViewer.js:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    $find("reportViewer").add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged);
});

function viewerPropertyChanged(sender, e) {
    if (e.get_propertyName() == "isLoading") {
        if ($find("reportViewer").get_isLoading()) {
            // Do something when loading starts
        }
        else {
            // Do something when loading stops
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This does look like a more elegant solution, but I'm not set up to test it out anymore.

Comment: @ahm126: Fair enough, hopefully others may find it useful.

Comment: From my experience this doesn't work with IE8. Other browsers are ok

Comment: @Johann, that's interesting, as our target browser is IE8 and the above approach is working for us.... I can easily believe that a non-intuitive IE setting or the like might be getting in the way though.

Comment: @Matt Any chance to see the sample code in action [github / some other means..] Since i am not been able to find out / define the js file ReportViewer.js to try this solution

Comment: @Jibin, assuming you've got a WebForms project already (or an MVC one with an embedded aspx), the last snippet in the answer is all you need to put in ReportViewer.js (you don't have to name it that). Place this somewhere the ScriptManager can reach it and away you go... I'll see about adding more detail to the answer.

Comment: @Matt I tried to implement it in an MVC one with embedded aspx https://github.com/armanio123/ReportViewerForMvc

Comment: @Jibin, I haven't tried referencing scripts in an external assembly. Not sure whether ScriptManager can even deal with that. Have you tried putting the script in your example project to see if that's the issue?

Comment: I tried that way. I can access the ReportViewerControl using jquery $('#ReportViewer1') , but when i try to add .add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged); to it  i am getting an error that .add_propertyChanged is not a function

Comment: @JibinMathew I have also hit the add_propertyChanged is not a function, I can see it in an ajax js file that is being loaded, did you find a resolution?

Comment: @Hank NOt yet. Now i am migrating to the latest version of report viewer and this problem solved to some extend

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this using JQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_DefaultContent_AdminContent_reportViewer').ClientController.CustomOnReportLoaded = function () { 
alert('You see this after Report is Generated');
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = Sys.Application;
    app.add_init(ApplicationInit);

    function ApplicationInit(sender) {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        $('#ReportViewer1_ctl05').css('width', '1047px');
        if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest)
        }
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        var reportViewerControlId = "ReportViewer1";
        if (sender._postBackControlClientIDs[0].indexOf(reportViewerControlId) >= 0) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
</script>
```

EndRequest function will be triggered once report rendering gets completed.