# Report viewer print dialog javascript rendering issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

On my web forms page I have a report viewer control. I want this control to only show the print dialog so I set display CSS attribute of the report viewer to none.
The user will be presented the print dialog after the report is loaded so he can print the report and the form will close.
The javascript code for this is as follows:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //Check if the query string contains parameters for printing or exporting
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var reportViewer = $find('<%=ReportViewer1.ClientID %>');

            //Add event handler to the reportviewer. When the loading is done, open the print dialog
            //See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194972/cant-find-reportviewer-event-for-rendering-complete
            Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
                reportViewer.add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged);
            });

            function viewerPropertyChanged(sender, e) {
                if (e.get_propertyName() == "isLoading") {
                    if (reportViewer.get_isLoading()) {
                        //Do something when loading starts
                    }
                    else {
                        //Do something when loading stops
                        var panelReportViewer = document.getElementById('<%=PanelReportViewer.ClientID%>');
                        if (panelReportViewer.style.display == "none") //if there are no server side errors this panel is not displayed
                        {
                            DoOutputAction(reportViewer);
                            window.close();
                        }
                        else {
                            divPleaseWait.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The contents of DoOuputAction:

```
function ClientPrint(reportViewerControl) {

    if (reportViewerControl != null) {
        //Check if a report is loaded and not an error message is shown
        var reportArea = reportViewerControl.get_reportAreaContentType();
        if (reportArea == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) {
            reportViewerControl.invokePrintDialog();
        }
    }
}

function ClientExport(reportViewerControl) {

    if (reportViewerControl != null) {
        //Check if a report is loaded and not an error message is shown
        var reportArea = reportViewerControl.get_reportAreaContentType();
        if (reportArea == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) {
            reportViewerControl.exportReport("PDF");
        }
    }
}

function DoOutputAction(reportViewerControl) {
    var param = $.getUrlVar('action');
    switch (param) {
        case 'print':
            ClientPrint(reportViewerControl);
            break;
        case 'PDF':
            ClientExport(reportViewerControl);
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm developing this on my own PC with IE11, IIS 8.5. This works fine.
When I publish this out to my test server, also IIS 8.5 and IE11, the print dialog is not shown!
After investigating with the Developer Tools of IE, I noticed that the rendered javascript for showing the print dialog in Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd is different!
I'm showing only the contents that are different.

My pc:

```
PrintDialog: function()
{
    var printInfo = this.m_printInfo;
    if (printInfo == null)
        return false;

    var printObjectId = this.ReportViewerId + "_PrintObj";

    // Load the print control if it hasn't happened already
    var printObj = $get(printObjectId);
    if (printObj == null)
    {
        try
        {
            printObj = document.createElement("OBJECT");
            printObj.id = printObjectId;
            printObj.style.display = "none";
            printObj.ReportViewer = this;
            // Codebase must be before classid in order to download the control
            printObj.codeBase = printInfo.CabUrl;
            printObj.setAttribute("VIEWASTEXT", "");
            var reportViewer = $get(this.ReportViewerId);
            var printFunction = function() { this.ReportViewer.Print(false); };

            if (_$RVCommon.isIE10OrLower()) {
                printObj.onreadystatechange = printFunction;
                //Element must be added before printing occurs as the event can fire before this is added to the window.
                reportViewer.appendChild(printObj);
                printObj.classid = "CLSID:" + printInfo.CabClsid;
            } else {
                // printObj.onreadystatechange doesn't work on IE11 and beyond. The following is supported.
                printObj.addEventListener("readystatechange", printFunction);
                // Starting IE11, activex controls embedded in object elements aren't loaded if the classID isn't set before adding them to the tree.
                // If this behavior would be in previous versions as well, the onreadystatechange event wouldn't fire.
                // That's why the special behavior only for IE11.
                printObj.classid = "CLSID:" + printInfo.CabClsid;
                reportViewer.appendChild(printObj);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (exception)
        {
            alert(this.UnableToLoadPrintMessage);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Print(true);
    }
},
```

The Print Dialog function rendered from the server:

```
PrintDialog: function()
{
    var printInfo = this.m_printInfo;
    if (printInfo == null)
        return false;

    var printObjectId = this.ReportViewerId + "_PrintObj";

    // Load the print control if it hasn't happened already
    var printObj = $get(printObjectId);
    if (printObj == null)
    {
        printObj = document.createElement("OBJECT");
        printObj.id = printObjectId;
        printObj.onreadystatechange = this.OnPrintLoaded;
        printObj.style.display = "none";
        printObj.ReportViewer = this;
        // Codebase must be before classid in order to download the control
        printObj.codeBase = printInfo.CabUrl;
        printObj.setAttribute("VIEWASTEXT", "");

        //Element must be added before printing occurs as the event can fire before this is added to the window.
        var reportViewer = $get(this.ReportViewerId);
        reportViewer.appendChild(printObj);

        printObj.classid = "CLSID:" + printInfo.CabClsid;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Print();
    }
},
```

As you can see there are a lot of differences!

The web.config's of both machines are the same. The report viewer version is the same. The AjaxControlToolKit dll's are the same.

Has anyone experienced the same problem yet?

Thanks for your help.